# how to create link for ics type file that take updated event automatically in c#

Tags: c#, icalendar

I want to create a link so it will update event automatically so each time not require to import in C#.

I have tried about web call but there is not specify how to local files works with web call and get updated file all time.

Comment: Can you show what you tried so far and where you get stuck?

Comment: Also please clarifty whether the code is to 

1) provide the ics feed (in which case essentially the code runs each time sometime calls the url/code, so ics events should always be up to date or 2) read someone else's ics feed, in which case your code can only determine how often it reads the feed and checks for updates and hope that the feed is up to date.